# Java SDK Reporting Wrong Architecture on Mac M1

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-11

I have a strange java issue.  I'm working on a MacBook Air and doing some Java development work.  I need my code to do the following:

```
// pseudo code
if (intel) {
   // Load docker 
} else if (arm) {
   // Load ARM docker
}
```

It works for Intel and Linux-based ARM architecture.  But for my M1 MacBook Air, it reports that the OS is `Mac OS X` but the architecture is reported as `x86`.  Because of that last issue, I can't distinguish between the ARM and Intel machines.

Here's the JDK version I'm running.  I feel like I'm missing something here, but is there some way I can write this code so that I can determine whether the code is running on an M1 or an Intel?

```
 ~ java --version
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.50+19-CA (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.50+19-CA (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode)
(base) ➜  ~ java -XshowSettings 2>&1 | grep "  os."
    os.arch = x86_64
    os.name = Mac OS X
    os.version = 11.5
```

Answer (score 8):

Its probably because you're actually running a x86_64 Java VM through Rosetta on your M1 Macbook. At least AdoptOpenJDK doesn't even offer a native m1 version of Java 11. For Java 17, there is a native aarch64 version available: https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk17&jvmVariant=hotspot

In the [*Activity Monitor*](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac) app bundled with your map, you can verify if an app (“process”) is running natively versus running under [Rosetta 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2). Find your process, likely named `java`, and look at the *Kind* column. Native apps say `Apple` while apps under Rosetta 2 say `Intel`.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. I think you're right. I'm running Zulu (who do offer an aarch build of Java 11) on my M1, same as OP, and I get 'aarch64' as os.arch. I guess they installed the non-native version

Comment: For the benefit of a n00b like me, is there a way to make sure that I'm installing the ARM version of the JDK?  I was using sdkman and I thought I was doing it.

Comment: @cgivre I do not use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/). I download installers from vendors such as [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) or Azul Systems (also, Pivotal, Red Hat/IBM, BellSoft, Microsoft, Amazon, Oracle, SAP, etc.). When on their download page, pay attention to their labeling. Labels such as "macOS x64" or "x86-64" means *Intel* machines. If need be, look for some section or link to "other platforms". Look for "macOS aarch64" or "macOS ARM" for a JDK optimized for your [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) [M1 chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1).

Comment: In addition to @BasilBourque's answer, I can also recommend using https://brew.sh and install it with 'brew install java' as well as keep it updated with that as well. It should automatically install the native version.